# ExecutorService with number of running tasks

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I want to get the number of tasks that are submitted to an executor service and not yet finished (i.e currently running/active or queued). Executor service does not have an inbuilt method for this.

```
((ThreadPoolExecutor) executorService).getActiveCount()
```

This "Returns the approximate number of threads that are actively executing tasks."

Is this a valid alternative to maintaining, say, a volatile counter ?
Why is it approximate ? 
Will I actually be better off maintaining a counter ?
Why does executor service not have an in-built method for this ?

Comment: if you want to wait for your tasks to complete, you can use an ExecutorCompletionService.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the task: It would only be possible to tell you the exact number, if you halt the system, count, return, start the system. 
Otherwise: During counting, threads may start and end, so the number is an approximation.

See the implementation in OpenJDK8:

```
1812    public int More ...getActiveCount() {
1813        final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
1814        mainLock.lock();
1815        try {
1816            int n = 0;
1817            for (Worker w : workers)
1818                if (w.isLocked())
1819                    ++n;
1820            return n;
1821        } finally {
1822            mainLock.unlock();
1823        }
1824    }
```

The implementation is straight forward, but it is like counting ants without killing them: They will come and go while you count.

Comment: So, if new ants don't come while I count (I can make sure of that) I will get a result which will say at most x tasks running ? Because a task might end while I was counting ?

Comment: Would you suggest I maintain a counter or getActiveCount is reliable ?

Comment: Thats correct. Regarding the exact counter: What is your plan? what do you need this counter for? Usually, when you stop your system you wait dome seconds, check if all are gone, repeat until you are sick of it, send interrupts, wait agsin, kill them all or get killed by os. For waterline display, the builtin counter is fine for me, also for graphs or such stuff. If you maintain so many  tasks, that counting them in the loop is very expensive, you may want the counter.

Comment: In my use case there won't be more than 8-9 tasks getting executed. I basically want to kill my process if no task is being executed.

Comment: I suppose, you will have to wait / monitor a bit and then finish, when the counter reached null. If this is too slow for your purpose you need to implement a counter or worker registry with direct connection to the worker lifecycle yourself.